# Set thickness on QLCDNumber

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and now I am playing with [trolltech tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial-t5.html).

I managed to customize the QLCDNumber *color* and *background* using `setPalette` method, but I can't seem to change the *thickness*. I understand that there is no letter, so `setFont` method can't be used, so I tried `setBrush`, but still no progress.

Is it possible to set the thickness somehow? If not, please help me understand why.

---

**edit**

as @webclectic points out, it is necessary to reimplement `paintEvent`. But it calls `drawString`, which calls `drawDigit` which calls `drawSegment` which is in `QLCDNumberPrivate` class (??) [see source](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid398B6690BF49BE23038F67CA39AE2FFE4D06C834.aspx). I have no idea how to reimplement it: since no methods are virtual, I'd have to rewrite them all, am I right? Is there any other way except rewrite the class completely?

Comment: The best you can do is to copy all the class, rename it and add the functionality you desire. QLcdNumber is one of the oldest parts of Qt, so it lacks many of the handy functions newer classes have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you want since the width of the LCD number is hardcoded (check this [thread](http://www.qtforum.org/article/32908/qlcdnumber-font-too-skinny-in-4-6-how-to-make-it-thick.html)).

One solution is to subclass `QLcdNumber` and reimplement the `paintEvent` where you will specify the desired width.